# What was the US Navy's "fleet marine force" in 1944-45?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, naval

My dad joined the navy in 1944.  After he pissed off his Navy chief in boot camp, he was assigned to what he called the Fleet Marines.  Whenever I try and look up *fleet marines* it always tries to give me info on the regular marines.  He said his *fleet marine force* was involved in doing diversionary attacks during invasions of several pacific islands. On his service record for the time period it says NSO Navy 926.  Any info out there on Naval Fleet Marines or NSO Navy 926?

Comment: Wikipedia has a page for the [fleet marine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleet_Marine_Force) force.

Comment: NSO is usually Navy Supply Officer. A Google search for "[Navy 926](https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=1527&bih=800&ei=BLU2WqOgL8acgAazw6yoAg&q=%22Navy+926%22&oq=%22Navy+926%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1l10.10472.10472.0.10785.1.1.0.0.0.0.97.97.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.96....0.lOYatPfmzmQ)" gives a lot of results for the US naval base at Guam.

Comment: @justCal I've seen it used in US Navy action reports. It's listed [here](http://acronymsandslang.com/meaning-of/government-and-military/Nso.html) for example. I've also seen it in later Sec-Nav reports where it's used for [Nuclear Weapons Safety Officer](http://govdocs.rutgers.edu/mil/navy/3120.32D.pdf), but in this context that seems unlikely. :)

Comment: Not sure if this helps but my father's Naval papers says date of entry into active service 7-22-44. Not sure if that means he joined on that date or entered boot camp on that date or was assigned his first post somewhere on that date. It also says ratings held     AS    S2c   S1c          I don't know what any of those mean either.  I  thought he mentioned Tinian in his stories and also Guam

Comment: Those would be Apprentice Seaman, Seaman 2nd Class ,Seaman 1st Class.

Answer (score 2):

The 'Fleet Marine Force' was the WW2 designation for what we now typically refer to as 'the Marines'.  It took this designation in the years between WW1 and the start of WW2, when it was realized that Japans designs on the Pacific would result in the need for a more specialized force, capable of amphibious operations. From [Western Pacific Operations](http://www.marines.mil/Portals/59/Publications/History%20of%20the%20U.S.%20Marine%20Corps%20in%20WWII%20Vol%20IV%20-%20Western%20Pacific%20Operations%20%20PCN%2019000262700_1.pdf)
HISTORY OF U. S . MARINE CORPS
OPERATIONS IN WORLD WAR II, vol iv

> By 1927, a Joint Army-Navy Board recommended that the Marine Corps, in
>   keeping with its close association with the Navy, be given special
>   preparation for the conduct of amphibious warfare.

in response,

> ...recommendations were approved and thus was created on 7 December
>   1933 the Fleet Marine Force with headquarters at Quantico, Virginia,
>   an event that was to be described as  perhaps "the most significant
>   development within the Marine Corps ."

The linked article has an entire chapter which goes in depth on the background and formation of the Fleet Marines.

---

Concerning other parts of your question, comments by  sempaiscuba point out that the NSO designation can indicate Naval Supply Officer. Part of the organizational information on pg 24 of the above pdf includes:

> ...recommended the creation of Headquarters, Amphibious Troops,
>   Pacific, to include I Marine Amphibious Corps, II Marine Amphibious
>   Corps, an Army Corps, along with Defense Troops, Expeditionary Troops
>   Artillery, and the *Service of Supply, Amphibious Troops Pacific* .

So we see indications of the inclusion of a supply unit within the Fleet Marines organizational structure.

---

In reference to the 926 number you ask about, the military uses numeric codes to designate locations, and these can be looked up in numerous locations.The 926 designation is listed [here](https://bluejacket.com/usn-usmc_ww2_location-codes.html) as:

- 926  SF  Guam, Marianas Islands

(the SF indicated fleet post office San Francisco, so Pacific Fleet)

---

In the comments you also queried concerning other designations you found :

> 'ratings held AS S2c S1c'

These are essentially the ranks your father held. You can find some info [here](http://world-war-2.wikia.com/wiki/United_States_Navy_Rank_Insignia) showing what insignia and the progression of the enlisted ranks. The ranks you list represent are shown as:

- AS   Apprentice Seaman
- s2c  Seaman Second Class
- s1c  Seaman First Class